# parsing pdf metadata date does not work for all pdfs

Tags: python, datetime, parsing, pdf, metadata

I'm trying to get the modification date for multiple pdfs using pdfminer

```
import os
import re
from datetime import datetime
from pdfminer3.pdfparser import PDFParser
from pdfminer3.pdfdocument import PDFDocument


# This function convers the date string to a datetime object
def get_pdf_date(pd):
    dtformat = "%Y%m%d%H%M%S"
    clean = pd.decode("utf-8").replace("D:", "").split('+')[0]
    return datetime.strptime(re.sub('[^0-9]', '', clean), dtformat)


path = "C:\\Users\\asus\\Desktop\\storage"
for file in os.listdir(path):
    try:
        fp = open(os.path.join(path, file), "rb")
        parser = PDFParser(fp)
        doc = PDFDocument(parser)
        pdf_creation_date = doc.info[0]["CreationDate"]
        print(str(pdf_creation_date) + ", " + str(get_pdf_date(pdf_creation_date)))
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e) + " => " + str(pdf_creation_date))
```

This is the output that I get :

b"D:20151004081456+01'00'", 2015-10-04 08:14:56

b'D:20161029124239', 2016-10-29 12:42:39

b"D:20160727173724+05'30'", 2016-07-27 17:37:24

b"D:20170526150059+05'30'", 2017-05-26 15:00:59

b'D:20190218122459', 2019-02-18 12:24:59

**unconverted data remains: 0600 => b"D:20151017020552-06'00'"**

b"D:20180302120823+00'00'", 2018-03-02 12:08:23

b"D:20150317171945+05'30'", 2015-03-17 17:19:45

b"D:20140405150714+01'00'", 2014-04-05 15:07:14

b'D:20190313161243Z', 2019-03-13 16:12:43

b'D:20160523204913', 2016-05-23 20:49:13

b"D:20150716000009+05'30'", 2015-07-16 00:00:09

b"D:20150923145114+05'30'", 2015-09-23 14:51:14
b"D:20150703193510+05'30'", 2015-07-03 19:35:10

b"D:20170907220317+16'33'", 2017-09-07 22:03:17

**unconverted data remains: 1200 => b"D:20160407192544-12'00'"**

As you can see, the parsing function that I used doesn't work all the time, and thats because each pdf seems to have its own date syntax. However I noticed that Foxit Reader always gets the metadata correctly as shown in the picture below

[image]

So I'm wondering how I can implement such thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The failing dates have a minus sign in them for the time zone offset:

```
D:20160407192544-12'00'
```

This line in your code is only expecting a plus sign (or, implicitly, no time zone offset):

```
clean = pd.decode("utf-8").replace("D:", "").split('+')[0]
```

Your code needs to handle both positive and negative time zone offsets.